# Generating A Consistent ID For A Given Computer In Flex/Air

Tags: apache-flex, air, hardware

In C++ I Can Read The MAC Address Of The NIC and Use It To Generate A Unique Identifier For Each Computer That Interacts With My Web Service.  Even If The User Deletes Their Cookies, And Temporary Internet Files, Reformats Their HardDrive And Installs A Different Version Of Windows, That Computer Still Generates The Same Unique ID.

How Can I Create Such A Unique Key Using Flex Or Air?  The Number Has To Be Either Hardware Based Or Similarly Tamper Resistant.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Air 2 you can spawn a native process and get a result back.  You'll need to use that to get access to low level info like this.